# Missing keyword error from partition by statement

Tags: oracle, sas

I'm trying to find a scenario where a customer was contacted more than 3 times in a 7 day rolling period.  Because I operate in SAS for nearly everything, to do this I was trying to connect to the oracle side and use a partition statement to get what I need.  I created a test scenario to try to get it to work but currently it's giving me a "Missing Keyword" error and I can't seem to see what it's missing.

This is my test dataset:

```
data work.have;
  input customer_id id call_date yymmdd10.;
  format call_date yymmdd10.;
cards;
111 1111 2019-03-01
111 1112 2019-03-01
111 1113 2019-03-02
111 1114 2019-03-03
111 1115 2019-03-04
111 1116 2019-03-05
111 1117 2019-03-06
111 1118 2019-03-07
111 1119 2019-03-08
111 1120 2019-03-09
111 1121 2019-04-01
222 1122 2019-02-01
222 1123 2019-03-02
222 1124 2019-03-03
222 1125 2019-03-01
222 1126 2019-03-11
222 1127 2019-03-12
222 1128 2019-03-13
;
run;
```

And here is the code I have so far:

```
proc sql;
connect to oracle as test (user=&user. pw=&pass. path='path');
  create table work.want as
  select * from connection to test (
    select id, call_date, customer_id, call_num
    from (select id, call_date, customer_id,
      count(id) over (partition by customer_id order by call_date range between interval 6 day preceding and current row) call_num
      from work.have where call_date between '2019-02-22' and '2019-03-31' order by customer_id, id) t
    where call_num >= 4
  );
disconnect from test;
quit;
```

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm hoping it's something easy that my eyes are just blurring over.

Comment: Thank you!  I knew I was glazing over something simple.  Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing single quotes in your [interval literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-DC8D1DAD-7D04-45EA-9546-82810CD09A1B):

[image: Syntax for interval literal]

The quotes are not optional. So it needs to be:

```
...
      count(id) over (partition by customer_id order by call_date range between interval '6' day preceding and current row) call_num
                                                                                ---------^ ^
...
```